# Getting HtmlUnit to list all of the elements including redirects requested after page load

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'd like to get HtmlUnit to tell me all of the requests it made after a page load is complete. It's not hard to inspect the DOM for elements that exist after the page load. However, I'd like to see everything in the chain of redirects. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from WebConnectionWrapper class like:

```
public class WebConnectionFilter:WebConnectionWrapper
{   
    public override WebResponse getResponse(WebRequestSettings settings)
    {
        String currentRequestUrl = settings.getUrl();
        // Do whatever you want with URL
        return base.getResponse(settings);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this class like:

```
WebClient client = getNewClient();
client.setWebConnection(new WebConnectionFilter(client));
```

Now any request out of WebClient passes through getResponse method

PS: I'm not using the latest version of HtmlUnit, so the name of WebConnectionWrapper class may be changed in newer versions.

Comment: This looks rather like C#. HtmlUnit is a Java library.

Comment: Yes, I use C# port of HtmlUnit lib. But conceptually there is no difference, so you can implement it in Java.